# Unitary dual of the complex motion group $\mathbb C^2 \rtimes SU(2)$?

Tags: rt.representation-theory, lie-groups, fourier-analysis, harmonic-analysis, unitary-representations

The real motion group of $\mathbb R^2$, $M(2)$ is the semi-direct product of $\mathbb R^2$ with the special orthogonal group $K = SO(2)$. A well
known fact is that the unitary dual $\hat{G}$, of $G$ is precisely the collection [M. Sugiura: Unitary Representations and Harmonic Analysis. Kodansha Scientific books, Tokyo (1975), p: 165](https://books.google.fr/books?hl=fr&lr=&id=yanslHJYvAIC&oi=fnd&pg=PP1&dq=Sugiura,+M.:+Unitary+Representations+and+Harmonic+Analysis.+&ots=jbme2tqblC&sig=7EAMMUlHDdNk4vj7Hs6Q9VnO_98#v=onepage&q=Sugiura%2C%20M.%3A%20Unitary%20Representations%20and%20Harmonic%20Analysis.&f=false)
$$\{\pi_\lambda,\,  \lambda>0  \}\cup\{\chi_n: \, n\in \mathbb Z \},$$ 
where $[\pi_{\lambda}(z,e^{i\alpha})u](s) = e^{i\lambda \left<z,e^{is}\right>} u(s-\alpha)$ for $u\in L^2([0,2\pi])$ and where $\chi_n(z,e^{i\alpha})=e^{in\alpha}$.

Now, any references or someone can help me to write the analog of that in the cases of the complex motion group $G=\mathbb C^2 \rtimes SU(2)$ ?
Thank you in advance
 $$................$$
Following the remark in [Dual topology of the motion groups, p: 398](https://www.degruyter.com/view/j/form.2010.22.issue-2/forum.2010.022/forum.2010.022.xml), I tried to construct this representation!!

For each linear form $l$ on $\mathbb C^2$ and any irreducible unitary representation $\rho$ of the stabilizer $S_l$ of l in $SU(2)$, we have that $\, \sigma_{(\rho,l)}=\rho\otimes\chi_l \, $ is an irreducible unitary representation of $H_l = S_l\rtimes \mathbb C^2$ whose restriction to $\mathbb C^2$ is a multiple of the character $\chi_l$ of $\mathbb C^2$ given by $\chi_l(z) = e^{−i\left<l,z\right>}$ ($z\in \mathbb C^2$), and the induced representation $\pi_(\rho,l) := ind^{G}_{H_l} \sigma(\rho,l)$ is an irreducible representation of $G$.

If $r > 0$ is the radius of the sphere, we denote by $\chi_r$ the character associated with the linear form $l_r$ which is identified with the vector $(0, . . . , 0, r)^t$ .The stabilizer $S_{l_{r}}$ of $l_{r}$ is the subgroup $SU (1)$. Let us write $\rho_\mu$ instead of $\rho$ for the representation of $SU(1)$ with highest weight $\mu$ and $\pi(\mu,r)$ instead of $\pi(\rho_\mu,l_r)$. The representation $\pi(\mu,r)$ is realized on $L^2(SU(2))$ as follows; for all $(A, z)\in  G$ and all $B \in SU(2)$
$$(*) \quad \pi(\mu,r)(A,z)F(B)=e^{i\left<B l_r, z\right>} F(A^{-1}B), \quad F\in L^2(SU(2)).$$
Finally, the unitary dual $\hat{G}$, of $G$ is precisely the collection:
$$\{r>0, \rho\in\hat{SU(1)}  \}\cup\{\pi \in\hat{SU(2)} \}.$$

Thank you in advance for any comments or suggestions!!

Comment: [Same ref. as before](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/290156/unitary-dual-of-the-motion-group-mn-for-n-2). (Give a man a fish...)

Comment: @ F. Ziegler, thanks for the reference, it's very nice. But for me I'm looking for an explicit expression of this representation as the case given above for $\mathbb R^2 \rtimes SO(2)$ ?

Comment: You just need to learn to write induced representations in whatever way you regard as “explicit”. (Note that’s subjective and not a mathematically well-defined concept. But I can sympathize that some realizations are friendlier than others. If I remember correctly, [Kirillov’s book](https://www.ams.org/mathscinet-getitem?mr=412321) is quite helpful for that.)

Comment: Dear F. Ziegler, using the method of induction of Mackey, I tried to build this representation, is that correct?

Comment: “$SU(1)$” (and attendant constructs) can be drastically simplified...

Comment: Yes, $\hat{SU(1)}=\{\chi_m : m\in \mathbb Z\}$, where $\chi_m(z)=z^m$.

Comment: $SU(1) =\{1\}$.

Comment: Then, the unitary dual $\hat{G}$, of $G$ is just the collection:  $\{r>0 \}\cup\{\pi \in\hat{SU(2)} \}$?

Comment: Last comment sounds right. You should probably restore the original question, and make your proposed solution an *answer*.

Comment: Ok, last question,  In the case of $\mathbb R^2 \rtimes SO(2)$, the scalar product that appears in the expression  of $\pi_\lambda$ is given by $\left<z,e^{is}\right>$; where $\left<z,w\right>=\Re(z.\overline{w})$. Now, what is it  $\left<B l_r, z\right>$  that appears in $(*)$ in our case?  Is: $\left<B l_r, z\right>=r\left<B, z\right>$, where $\left<z,w\right>=\Re(z.\overline{w})$ also ?

Comment: $(*)=e^{ir\langle u,z\rangle}F(A^{-1}u)$ where $u=Bl_1\in S^3\simeq SU(2)$ and $\langle u,z\rangle=\mathrm{Re}(\bar u_1z_1+\bar u_2z_2)$.  No $\mu$!